# Opinion on security of my form submit / display

Tags: php, security

I'm building a review site that will allow users to submit reviews which will be stored in a MySQL DB. Reviews will be manually reviewed by me for content, and then displayed on my site. Here's my custom function for cleaning the data (every item on the form is passed to this function):

```
function cleanDataForDB($data) {
$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $data = stripslashes($data);

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

return $data;
```

}

I haven't written the script to display the reviews once they've been approved yet, but I was planning on just passing all the fields from my MySQL table through html_entity_decode() function and writing them to the HTML of my page.

Does anyone see any obvious security holes in this plan? It seems pretty safe to me, but this is the first site I've built that allows user-submitted data, so I want to be sure I'm not leaving myself vulnerable.

Thanks!

Comment: The magic quotes correction should be done once and at a central place. See manual for something like `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $_POST = array_map("stripslashes", $_POST); $_GET... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do database escaping on the data before putting it into the DB, and do HTML escaping on pulling it out.  That way, you can process the HTML in the user's posts in the future without finding "oops, I mangled it".

The best way to escape the data for insert is to use PDO.

For displaying the data, `htmlentities` is probably sufficient.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is often better, but also *depends* the correct charset parameter to be effective.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDO and the php.net manual isn't super helpful on the topic. You're saying this is something I should use in addition to the custom function I'm already using? I assume PDO provides more robust security somehow?

Comment: @Chris: Not in addition, but instead. Read up on [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+prepared+statements)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Borealid, but would like to add that you may want to use preg_replace() to completely remove any JavaScript scripting, rather than just stripping the tags from it.

Comment: I found a couple regexes to do this (see link), but shouldn't strip_tags() make this unnecessary? (btw, no carriage returns in comments? very frustrating for trying to write code! :) LINK: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/php-regex/removing-javascript-from-string/